# Image links from lower folder not working

Tags: html, css, image

So I have my index and stylesheet files in the root folder (ie public html). Images, are set in a lower folder (public html/images). I have div containers with background images that will not show up. In the css, the code is as follows:

```
#exampleDiv{
    background-image: url("images/image.jpg");
    background-size: 40px 40px;
}
```

This works perfectly fine when I load the site from my desktop files. However, as soon as I run it on the actual server the images just aren't found. I have tried everything from adding a "/" in front of "images/image.jpg", I have checked, rechecked and rechecked to make sure my code is sound and there are no typos. If I place the image in the root directory (public html) that contains the index and stylesheets and remove the "images/" part from "images/image.jpg" the images show up just fine. Any ideas? I really don't understand why this wouldn't be working and yes, my site cache is flushed and loading all of the changes I make to the pages.

Edit: I also have tried a variety of backward slashes as well as "../" and "../../"

Edit: I figured it out!

Comment: Do you have the access rights on the *images* folder on the server?

Comment: Did you tried adding `../` to your url?

Comment: I have tried adding "../" and that did not work. I do not know for sure if I have access rights, how would I set that up/check? I have not had this problem before.

Answer (score 1):

I am an idiot. My image folder is actually called "icons" and I just used "images" as an example. When I checked to see if I could access that via "http://website.com/icons" apparently the icons folder is used internally and I guess there is a conflict. Now I know. Good lesson to learn.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, your file structure looks something a little like this?

```
html/
|-index.html
|-style.css
|-images/
    |-image.jpg
```

Well there are a few things you could try. These are what I usually do first when my paths don't work as expected. If you are migrating from a windows environment to a unix-based server, make sure that names you reference and the names of folders/files are the same case. You should also check file permissions on your server... you can use the command "chmod 755 -r html" in the file level above html to change them appropriately (On unix anyway). You could  also use "./" at the beginning of your referenced filename to explicitly state you want to route from the current directory.

Comment: The file structure is correct. All of the filenames are in the proper case and I have tried adding "./" with no luck. I will check permissions.

Comment: Oh yeah, also use sudo when using chmod!

Comment: Oh, if you want to check out the file permissions, you can do this either in command line using ls -la ... you will get a string that looks like "drwxr-xr-x" or "-rw-------", if you want to know what these mean exactly, you can check out [this](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/checking-linux-file-permissions-with-ls/) link. Most FTP clients with a GUI will also show these permissions (I know filezilla does anyway - you can even change the permissions from within the client)

Comment: So I am able to check permissions in my file manager and the images by default are set to 644. The folder, by default, is set to 755. I messed around with the permissions and it still doesn't seem to work. I tried setting everything to 777 and I'm getting nothing :/

Comment: if you use an img tag in your index.html using <img src="images/image.jpg">, does the image display?

Comment: Good idea, but no luck. Tried <img src = "image.jpg"> to make sure my code was fine before trying "images/", "/images", "./images", and "../images" . I also messed with the privelages for each of those. What the heck :/

Comment: Yeah very odd... Maybe change the double quotes to single ones ? Haha Im out of ideas otherwise